# ColdFusion GC Overhead Limit while looping over API Json Response

Tags: json, loops, memory-leaks, coldfusion, garbage-collection

To start, I understand what the "GC Overhead limit" error means, in general. I received this message while running a script that does the following:

1. Create Instance of an object that makes a CFHTTP GET request to an external API
2. Store JSON response (an array) as a property of the object Instance (i.e. VARIABLES.data)
3. Loop through the JSON response array using a `for in` loop
4. Create an instance on an object that calls a SQL Server Stored Procedure passing in the properties of the JSON object (the SQL Stored Procedure performs and UPDATE or INSERT based on the existence of a record for the object's key)

Debug output shows that the SP call takes between 3-12 milliseconds.

When I run this script with a limited dataset (~3,000 records), it runs to completion without throwing a GC exception.

When I run the script with the complete dataset (~14,000 records), the GC exception is thrown.

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
    for (LOCAL.WidgetJson in VARIABLES.data) {
        LOCAL.Widget=new Widget();
        LOCAL.Widget
            .save(argumentCollection=LOCAL.WidgetJson);
    }
```

Widget.cfc:

```
private void function saveStoredProc() {
    cfstoredproc(procedure="SaveWidget") {
        cfprocparam(
            dbvarname="@id",
            type="in",
            cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INT",
            value=VARIABLES.id
            );
        <!--- Rest of cfprocparam() tags here --->
}

private void function save() {
    for (LOCAL.Property in ARGUMENTS) {
        if  (StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS, LOCAL.Property)) {
            if  (IsSimpleValue(ARGUMENTS[LOCAL.Property])) {
                VARIABLES[LOCAL.Property] = Trim(ARGUMENTS[LOCAL.Property]);
            }
            else {
                VARIABLES[LOCAL.Property] = ARGUMENTS[LOCAL.Property];
            }
        }
    }

    saveStoredProc();
}
```

I'm wondering if the way that I'm creating objects or looping could be improved to prevent GC exceptions/memory leaks.

Any ideas for improvements?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using `variables` scope here? Why not use local scope and pass the id and params to the `saveStoredProc` function.

Comment: You could create a single instance of Widget before the loop and just call widget.save() and pass in the values in the loop.

Comment: Also consider using a bulk insert/update instead of many individual operations. When you get into thousands of queries, bulk operations are usually a lot more performant.

Comment: We have run into issues with CF saving data about each cfquery and cfqueryparam call in a request and never releasing it. Over time this builds up. The cfquery calls aren't bad by themselves so we usually can get around it by not using cfqueryparam for requests looping over a large amount of data. Otherwise we have to break up the long running requests into multiple requests which allows the memory leak to be garbage collected. I would not be surprised if that is what you are experiencing here.

Comment: @DanRoberts there's no CFQUERY/CFQUERYPARAM use here. I am making calls to a SQL Stored Procedure via CFSTOREDPROC/CFPROCPARAM.

Comment: Those are still bind variables, which sounds like they may be the root of the problem. Why not bulk import/update instead of many individual queries?

Comment: @Ageax, could you point me in the direction of how to do this? I've done BULK INSERTs with flat file uploads, but, I've never done it with multi-level JSON arrays.

Comment: @EricBelair yeah I was suggesting that you may be running into the same issue that exists for some other db tags. From the info you provided, what you are doing should not be an issue but I have run into that many times in CF. You can try using MAT and jmap to find the issue. Here is a page that talks about it in relation to a driver memory leak. I think this may be the memory leak I have run into many times in the past but don't recall...

https://www.hass.de/content/coldfusion-10-macromedia-database-drivers-leaking-memory

Comment: @EricBelair - You can use some of the newer JSON functions if you prefer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017. Though, no reason you couldn't just write the data out to a file and bulk insert the usual way. Either way the data's inserted into some sort of staging table and used to do a bulk update/insert based on matching id, which should be a lot faster and lighter than the many proc calls.

Comment: @DanRoberts - Interesting. Did you notice the same improvements switching drivers, too?

Comment: Thanks, @Ageax, I will look into this....

Comment: @Ageax it has been a while since I looked into this. I do recall trying out different drivers but don't believe it resolved it. However using the instructions there and some other places I was able to inspect the memory leak with cfquery/queryparam and see that it was holding on to arguments to every call of the tags which built up until out of memory

Comment: @DanRoberts - Yipes... that makes sense though. Ultimately, I'd probably still go with bulk operations over looping, but ... since it's an easy change, and the article suggests a different driver did resolve their issue, I'd be curious if it has any impact on Eric's code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the garbage collection will happen during a single request even if it is necessary. You could either increase memory or split this into multiple threads that process smaller amounts of data.

Comment: It actually does. I've setup long running tests that show that. However CF saves data about certain things while it is processing (aka memory leak) that builds up over time which may be what is happening here.

Comment: Good to know. In the past, I've used the following code to run a collection before looping through records to save butI'm not sure it would help in your situation.
<cfset loc.sys = CreateObject("java","java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime() />
<cfset loc.sys.GC()>